# adding to page url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('.toggles span').click(function() {
  $(".toggles span").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});


$('.spanish').click(function() {
  $(location).attr('href') + '/es');)
};
$('.english').click(function() {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("/es") > -1) {
        location.href = location.href.replace("/es", "");
      )
    };
```

```css
.spanish {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggles span:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.spanish:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.english:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.spanish:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.english {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="toggles">
    <span class="spanish">spanish</span> | <span class="english">english</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a function that would essentially toggle the pages between duplicate Spanish and english pages. So I am need to find a way to get the current url then add either "es" or "en" to the end of it to bring the user to either Spanish or English version of the page.

So if a user went to the english page `"example.com/page-1/"` and clicked the Spanish toggle at the top then their url would be `"example.com/page-1/es"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spanish').click(function () {
        $(location).attr('href') + '/es');
  )};
    $('.english').click(function () {
      if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es") > -1) {
       location.href=location.href.replace("/es", "");
  )};
)};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

<-----------------------Updated Solution Below!----------------------->

A suggestion below was to use a show / hide function when you click the button. Would this be done by creating two divs one with the class="englishText" the other class="spanishText" and by using the following.

```
      $(".spanish").on("click", function() {
    $(".englishText").hide();
    $(".spanishText").show();
  });

  $(".english").on("click", function() {
    $(".englishText").show();
    $(".spanishText").hide();
  });
```

EDIT - going with the show / hide function I created the code above and it works. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: _"(not sure how to remove the /es for the "english" toggle) "_ - what's so hard about using Google ... https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+remove+specific+string+from+end+of+string

Comment: `$(location).attr('href')`? Why not `location.href`? Anyway, can't you use standard string operations to test whether the `location.href` already ends with `'/es'`?

Comment: What if someone want to visit: example.com/page-1/es => not found

Comment: @CBroe sorry dude I must have been wording my search wrong because I had spent over an hour looking into this before posting. I have updated the post.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698) You are required to post a complete example of your code here, not a jsfiddle: [mcve]

Comment: Updated the post! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the location, the better way to do it (in my opinion) would be to load both pages in <iframe> s and toggle their visibility using your button